# Can I remove the paypal IPN on a per button basis

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-buttons

We currently have a bookings system on the site that uses the IPN.  We also have a couple of Paypal buttons for Paypal gift certificates.

When someone purchases the Paypal gift certificates the booking script receives the IPN and doesn't know what to do with the IPN and sends an error notice....

Is it possible to remove IPN for the Paypal  gift certificate buttons in the advanced settings on the button?  If so, how?

Comment: you can over-write the IPN URL specified in your paypal profile settings by
notify_url, but cant remove it

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I was hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the notify_url parameter in your HTML button code or general checkout forms for PayPal to override what's in the profile setting.  So you should actually be able to leave IPN disabled in your profile, but then include the notify_url parameter in your button to go ahead and send it just for that one button (or any buttons that you include it with).

Alternatively, you could adjust your current IPN script to handle the different transaction types accordingly.  IPN includes a txn_type parameter, so you could check that in your code and simply exit the script or do whatever you want with each individual transaction type.

Comment: Thank you. The script is a wordpress plugin. The plugin setup  requests that the link to the IPN script that came with the plugin be entered into the paypal IPN settings.  I'll check the developer's support forum for information about adding additional parameters to the script.  It would be nice if there could be "null" in the individual button settings on paypal.  I was hopeful. You've been very helpful.  Thank you  for taking the time to answer  such an elementary question.

Comment: You'll just need to extend the WP plugin with your own that overrides the default procedure and does it the way you need whether you decide to use notify_url on the button code or just update the IPN code to catch txn_type's you don't need to process.

Comment: The developer has told me which file to edit.  I'll need to research how to exclude the 2 gift certificate buttons.  Thanks again.